# Splitting a column into two before and after the first appearance of a delimiter "/"

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dplyr, stringr

I have the attached dataframe.

**DATA**

```
structure(list(associated_gene = c(NA, NA, "A4GALT", NA, NA, 
   "NOT FOUND"), chr_name = c("22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "NOT FOUND"
   ), chrom_start = c(42693910L, 42693843L, 42693321L, 42693665L, 
   42693653L, 0L), allele = c("G/A/T", "T/C", "G/C", "C/T", "G/A/T", 
   "NOT FOUND"), refsnp_id = c("rs778598915", "rs11541159", "rs397514502", 
   "rs762949801", "rs776304817", "NOT FOUND")), row.names = c("s3a", 
   "s3b", "s3c", "s3d", "s3e", "s3f"), class = "data.frame")
```

> ```
>     associated_gene  chr_name chrom_start    allele   refsnp_id
> s3a            <NA>        22    42693910     G/A/T rs778598915
> s3b            <NA>        22    42693843       T/C  rs11541159
> s3c          A4GALT        22    42693321       G/C rs397514502
> s3d            <NA>        22    42693665       C/T rs762949801
> s3e            <NA>        22    42693653     G/A/T rs776304817
> s3f       NOT FOUND NOT FOUND           0 NOT FOUND   NOT FOUND
> ```

I would like to split the allele column by the first "/" into two (Ref & Var) and insert them between $chrom_start and $refsnp_id

The ideal output is:

> ```
>      associated_gene  chr_name chrom_start   Ref   Var   refsnp_id
> s3a            <NA>         22    42693910     G   A/T rs778598915
> s3b            <NA>         22    42693843     T     C  rs11541159
> ```

I dont know if I can load awk, but in bash I'd do:

cat allele | awk -F"/" '{print $1 "\t" $2}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want your output for the last row, you can use one of the following :

Using `tidyr::separate`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df, allele,into = c("Ref", "Var"),sep = "/",extra = "merge",fill = "right")

#   associated_gene  chr_name chrom_start        Ref  Var   refsnp_id
#s3a            <NA>        22    42693910         G  A/T rs778598915
#s3b            <NA>        22    42693843         T    C  rs11541159
#s3c          A4GALT        22    42693321         G    C rs397514502
#s3d            <NA>        22    42693665         C    T rs762949801
#s3e            <NA>        22    42693653         G  A/T rs776304817
#s3f       NOT FOUND NOT FOUND           0 NOT FOUND <NA>   NOT FOUND
```

OR with `stringr::str_match`

```
stringr::str_match(df$allele, "(.*?)/(.*)")[,c(2, 3)]

#     [,1] [,2] 
#[1,] "G"  "A/T"
#[2,] "T"  "C"  
#[3,] "G"  "C"  
#[4,] "C"  "T"  
#[5,] "G"  "A/T"
#[6,] NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `extract` from `tidyr` to capture the characters that are not a `/`  (`[^/]+`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by a `/` and then capture the rest of the characters

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     extract(allele, into = c("Ref", "Var"), "^([^/]+)/(.*)")
#   associated_gene  chr_name chrom_start  Ref  Var   refsnp_id
#s3a            <NA>        22    42693910    G  A/T rs778598915
#s3b            <NA>        22    42693843    T    C  rs11541159
#s3c          A4GALT        22    42693321    G    C rs397514502
#s3d            <NA>        22    42693665    C    T rs762949801
#s3e            <NA>        22    42693653    G  A/T rs776304817
#s3f       NOT FOUND NOT FOUND           0 <NA> <NA>   NOT FOUND
```

---

Or another option is `str_split`

```
library(stringr)
do.call(rbind, str_split(df$allele, "/", 2))
```

---

Or create a delimiter with `sub` and read with `read.table/read.csv` in `base R`

```
df1[c("Ref", "Var")] <- read.table(text = sub("/", ";", df1$allele, 
    fixed = TRUE), header = FALSE, sep = ";", 
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE, fill = TRUE, na.strings = c("NOT FOUND", ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is by using the "stringr" package:

```
install.packages("stringr")
library(stringr)
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(associated_gene = c(NA, NA, "A4GALT", NA, NA, 
                               "NOT FOUND"), chr_name = c("22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "NOT FOUND"
                               ), chrom_start = c(42693910L, 42693843L, 42693321L, 42693665L, 
                                                  42693653L, 0L), allele = c("G/A/T", "T/C", "G/C", "C/T", "G/A/T", 
                                                                             "NOT FOUND"), refsnp_id = c("rs778598915", "rs11541159", "rs397514502", 
                                                                                                         "rs762949801", "rs776304817", "NOT FOUND")), row.names = c("s3a", "s3b", "s3c", "s3d", "s3e", "s3f"), class = "data.frame")
```

Create a new df containing the two new variables:

```
new_df <- data.frame(
Ref = str_extract(df$allele, "\\w(?=/)"), 
Var = str_extract(df$allele, "(?<=/)\\w.*")
  )
new_df
   Ref  Var
1    G  A/T
2    T    C
3    G    C
4    C    T
5    G  A/T
6 <NA> <NA>
```

And column-bind `new_df`with `df` (subtracting the now-obsolete `allele` column):

```
cbind(df[,-4], new_df)
    associated_gene  chr_name chrom_start   refsnp_id  Ref  Var
s3a            <NA>        22    42693910 rs778598915    G  A/T
s3b            <NA>        22    42693843  rs11541159    T    C
s3c          A4GALT        22    42693321 rs397514502    G    C
s3d            <NA>        22    42693665 rs762949801    C    T
s3e            <NA>        22    42693653 rs776304817    G  A/T
s3f       NOT FOUND NOT FOUND           0   NOT FOUND <NA> <NA>
```